# Why doesn't a DOM2"click" event work, when it does work for "mouseover"?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to show/hide a div using a click event on a link element. If I substitute `mouseover` for `click` then `workPane` does show visible with normal hover behavior. I'm using Firefox 6.0.2. The full code can be seen at [www.pricelearman.com/__dev](http://www.pricelearman.com/__dev) (2 underscores are needed)

```
function showWorkPane() {
    var _workID = document.getElementById("workID");
    _workID.addEventListener("click", showWorkPaneHandler, false);
}

function showWorkPaneHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _workPane = document.getElementById("workPane");
    _workPane.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: @anddoutoi It's less than 2 years old. So it's a little strange but not so much.

Comment: If you are clicking on a *link*, the page might follow link before you can see the effect of the click event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can tell the link `<a id="workID" href="#">WORK</a>` is not bound to a click event handler. In the screenshot you can see that you have set several events, but on click is not set.

[image: No Event Listener onClick is set for link]

In your [main.js](http://www.pricelearman.com/__dev/_js/main.js) you are calling the function showWorkPane() but in this function you define no event handler for onClick:

```
function showWorkPane() {
    var workID = document.getElementById("workID");
    workID.addEventListener("mouseover", showWorkPaneHandler, false);
    // add an event handler for click
}
```

To address your question: **Why doesn't a DOM2“click” event work, when it does work for “mouseover”?**

Well you have to bind both events (click and mouseover). And currently i am looking into your code and it looks like that the eventhandler onmouseout which fires `hideWorkPaneHandler(e)` will be in conflict with your intent to show the workPane.

The sequence of events is this

- user moves mouse over the link 'work'
- user click on link 'work' <-- currently there is no eventhandler for this you have to add it
- user moves mouse out of the link --> this fires `hideWorkPane(e)`

#### Update 1: Reason while it is not working

In the comments user [Felix King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) said: "I understand that question in such a way that binding the handler to mouseover works, but when the OP changes it to click, it does not work as expected."
Could you comment on that please. **Please put the non-working version with click online and link it here so we can take a look at it.**

Regardless if this is the case if you add all events (click, mouseover, mouseout) to the links you have to find a solution that clicking on a link does not come in conflict with moving the mouse away from the link (and firing mouseout).

#### Update 2: Code refactored

A helper function since events are not identical cross browser (see [quirksmode.org/ on events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target)). If you want you can use jQuery instead.

```
function getTargetFromEvent(e) {
    // http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    return targ;
}
```

I created a function that wraps the adding of event handlers. You can use it by calling it like this `addEventShowPaneHandler('mouseover');`

```
function addEventShowPaneHandler(eventType){
    document.getElementById("workID").addEventListener(eventType, showPaneHandler, false);
    document.getElementById("aboutID").addEventListener(eventType, showPaneHandler, false);
    document.getElementById("connectID").addEventListener(eventType, showPaneHandler, false);    
}
```

The following function replaces all your `show---PaneHandler(e)` and your `hide---PaneHandler(e)` functions. All you have to do is to add the corresponding pane id as a data-attribute inside your link. Example: `<li><a id="workID" data-paneId="workPane" href="#work">WORK</a></li>`

```
function showPaneHandler(e) { // suggestion to rename it to  togglePaneDisplay
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    console.log(e.type);
    var element = getTargetFromEvent(e); 
    // see nodeinformation attributes at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html 
    var paneId = element.attributes["data-paneId"].value;
    var pane = document.getElementById(paneId);

    if(pane.style.display == "block" || pane.style.display == "undefined")
    {
        pane.style.display = "none";   
    }else{
        pane.style.display = "block";           
    }     
}
```

So for each link in your navigation you add the data-paneId attribute with the corresponding id of the pane like this:

```
<nav role="navigation" id="pageNav">
<ul>
   <li><a id="workID" data-paneId="workPane" href="#work">WORK</a></li>  
   <li><a id="aboutID" data-paneId="aboutPane" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a id="connectID" data-paneId="connectPane" href="#connect">CONNECT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Let me know if you have more questions or if you need further help.

Comment: I understand that question in such a way that binding the handler to `mouseover` works, but when the OP *changes* it to `click`, it does not work as expected.

Comment: @threefouronesixonethree.

Comment: @threefouronesixonethree. I have accepted your answer. Thank you for a very thoughtful reply. But Felix Kling was right about how my question should be interpreted. So I'm trying to reframe my question in a new post. Hopefully this doesn't violate any stackoverflow rules.

Comment: @DouglasLearman AFAIK [editing your own question is approved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work/21789#21789). To make it clear that you changed the question a bit you could add a new headline by using `### Update ...`. The only think could be that you as a newish user [might be unable to edit your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103567/unable-to-edit-my-own-question-that-has-been-edited-by-another-user-who-included). But may be they fixed it by now. Anyway i am hapy you accepted this one and i will take a look at your new question.